# cpp make_shared for void pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I would like to use std::make_shared to create a void pointer. Since make_shared is supposed to be faster than shared_ptr(new T), and exception save I wonder if there is a library function to create a shared_ptr(new foo) in the make_shared way.

Comment: What type of object would it create?

Comment: THat is the problem there would have to be some different syntax to suplly that, e.g. make_void_shared<obj>(constructor params). I have no performance gain from static_pointer_cast<void>(make_shared<foo>(bar1,...,barn))

Comment: You're asking for a shared_ptr to wrap a void* which in turn points to a real object?  But what would be the point of that?

Comment: Not having to do the meory management (shared_ptr<void>) while having type erasure (as far as i can grasp the concept of type erasure)

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for e.g. `boost::any`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to boost any, I don't think I will need it this time after a first glance but it seems quite handy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can convert any `shared_ptr<foo>` to `shared_ptr<void>` without the loss of efficiency associated with `make_shared`:

```
#include <memory>

struct foo {};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<void> p = std::make_shared<foo>();
}
```

The conversion keeps the `foo` and the reference count in the same memory allocation, even though you now refer to it via a `void*`.

**Update**

How does this work?

The general structure of a `std::shared_ptr<foo>` is two pointers:

```
                          +------> foo
                          |         ^
p1  ---------> (refcount, +)        |
p2  --- foo* -----------------------+
```

`p1` points to a control block containing a reference count (actually two reference counts: one for strong owners and one for weak owners), a deleter, an allocator, and a pointer to the "dynamic" type of the object.  The "dynamic" type is the type of the object that the `shared_ptr<T>` constructor saw, say `Y` (which may or may not be the same as a `T`).

`p2` has type `T*` where the `T` is the same `T` as in `shared_ptr<T>`.  Think of this as the "static" type of the stored object.  When you dereference a `shared_ptr<T>`, it is `p2` that gets dereferenced.  When you destruct a `shared_ptr<T>`, and if the reference count goes to zero, it is the pointer in the control block that aids in the destruction of `foo`.

In the above diagram, both the control block and the `foo` are dynamically allocated.  `p1` is an owning pointer, and the pointer in the control block is an owning pointer.  `p2` is a non-owning pointer.  `p2`'s **only** function is dereference (arrow operator, `get()`, etc.).

When you use `make_shared<foo>()`, the implementation has the opportunity to put the `foo` right in the control block, alongside of the reference counts and other data:

```
p1  ---------> (refcount, foo)
p2  --- foo* --------------^
```

The optimization here is that there is now only a single allocation:  the control block which now embeds the `foo`.

When the above gets converted to a `shared_ptr<void>`, all that happens is:

```
p1  ---------> (refcount, foo)
p2  --- void* -------------^
```

I.e. The type of `p2` changes from `foo*` to `void*`.  That's it.  (besides incrementing/decrementing reference counts to account for a copy and destruction of a temporary -- which can be elided by construction from an rvalue).  When the reference count goes to zero, it is still the control block that destroys the `foo`, found via `p1`.  `p2` does not participate in the destruction operation.

`p1` actually points to a generic base class of the control block.  This base class is ignorant of the type `foo` stored in the derived control block.  The derived control block is constructed in `shared_ptr`'s constructor at the time the actual object type `Y` is known.  But from then on the `shared_ptr` can only communicate with the control block via a `control_block_base*`.  So things like destruction happen via a virtual function call.

The "move construction" of a `shared_ptr<void>` from an rvalue `shared_ptr<foo>` in C++11 merely has to copy the two internal pointers, and does not have to manipulate the reference count.  This is because the rvalue `shared_ptr<foo>` is about to go away anyway:

```
// shared_ptr<foo> constructed and destructed within this statement
std::shared_ptr<void> p = std::make_shared<foo>();
```

This can be seen most plainly in the `shared_ptr` constructor source code:

```
template<class _Tp>
template<class _Yp>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(shared_ptr<_Yp>&& __r,
                            typename enable_if<is_convertible<_Yp*, _Tp*>::value, __nat>::type)
         _NOEXCEPT
    : __ptr_(__r.__ptr_),
      __cntrl_(__r.__cntrl_)
{
    __r.__ptr_ = 0;
    __r.__cntrl_ = 0;
}
```

Before the converting construction the reference count is only 1.  And after the converting construction the reference count is still 1, with the source pointing to nothing just prior to its destructor running.  This, in a nutshell, is the joy of move semantics! :-)

Comment: how does this work? With compiler optimization (hate to rely on those)? My understanding tells me that with pure C++ the best I could expect would be move semantics. Upon reading this I would expect something more complicated going on.

Comment: excellent answer with great detail! Some overhead (as I was afraid) seems to be left (refcount increase, new shared pointer where p2 is of type void, release of the shared pointer (pointer to controlblock,pointer to object) where p2 is of the actual type) seems to stay though. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ted: Without the conversion to `shared_ptr<void>`, you're going to create `p` with RVO (return value optimization), meaning no copies, no reference count manipulation.  In C++11 the conversion to `shared_ptr<void>` is very nearly cost free, but not quite.  The `shared_ptr<foo>` is still created via RVO, but is an rvalue.  The construction of the `shared_ptr<void>` from this rvalue is then optimized to simply copy the two internal pointers and zero the two internal pointers of the rvalue source.  This does not touch the reference count.  2 loads and 4 stores (all non-atomic) is the extra cost.

Comment: Thanks for an awesome in depth explanation.