# What happens when using make_shared

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, make-shared

I'm interested if these two lines of code are the same:

```
shared_ptr<int> sp(new int(1)); // double allocation?
shared_ptr<int> sp(make_shared<int>(1)); // just one allocation?
```

If this is true could someone please explain why is it only one allocation in the second line?

Comment: To be clear, it's not a double allocation of the `int`. It's just two separate allocations: one for the `int` object and another for the `shared_ptr` control block. The second line is only a single allocation of both the `int` and the control block in one go.

Comment: see point 2 here: http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/

Comment: In the second case `make_shared` allocates both the `int` and the control block and is therefore free to allocate both in one go. In the first case you allocate the `int` and the constructor of `shared_ptr` allocates the control block and there is no way to unite the allocations.

Comment: N.B. there is no guarantee that `make_shared` only does one allocation, it's just _possible_ for the implementation to do a single allocation ... but if your implementation doesn't perform that optimization you should complain to your vendor (at least the GCC, LLVM and MSVC implementations do it, and `boost::make_shared` does too)

Comment: Here is another decent explanation of what is going on under the hood: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8646062/576911

Comment: duplicate of [Difference in make\_shared and normal shared\_ptr in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895648/difference-in-make-shared-and-normal-shared-ptr-in-c)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The first case does not perform a double allocation, it performs two allocations, one for the *managed object* and one for the *control block* of the `shared_ptr`.

For the second case, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) has a good explanation for why [std::make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) **usually** only performs one memory allocation it says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> This function typically allocates memory for the T object and for the
>   shared_ptr's control block with a single memory allocation **(it is a
>   non-binding requirement in the Standard)**. In contrast, the declaration
>   std::shared_ptr p(new T(Args...)) performs at least two memory
>   allocations, which may incur unnecessary overhead.

and from [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) section it says:

> When shared_ptr is created by calling std::make_shared or
>   std::allocate_shared, the memory for both the control block and the
>   managed object is created with a single allocation. The managed object
>   is constructed in-place in a data member of the control block. When
>   shared_ptr is created via one of the shared_ptr constructors, the
>   managed object and the control block must be allocated separately. In
>   this case, the control block stores a pointer to the managed object.

This `make_shared` description is consistent with the [C++11 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) which says in section `20.7.2.2.6` *shared_ptr creation*

> ```
> template<class T, class... Args> shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Args&&... args);
> template<class T, class A, class... Args>
>   shared_ptr<T> allocate_shared(const A& a, Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Remarks: Implementations should perform no more than one memory
>   allocation. [ Note: This provides efficiency equivalent to an
>   intrusive smart pointer. —end note ]
>
> [ Note: These functions will typically allocate more memory than
>   sizeof(T) to allow for internal bookkeeping structures such as the
>   reference counts. —end note ]

Herb Sutter has a more detailed explanation of the advantages of using `make_shared` in [GotW #89 Solution: Smart Pointers](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/) and points out some advantages:

- It reduces allocation overhead
- It improves locality.
- Avoids an explicit new.
- Avoids an exception safety issue.

Be aware that when using [std::weak_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) [using make_shared has some disadvantages](http://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/make_shared-almost-a-silver-bullet/).

Answer (score 5):

Explanation from [cppreference std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) in `Implementation notes` section

> In a typical implementation, std::shared_ptr holds only two pointers:
>
> 1. a pointer to the managed object
> 2. a pointer to control block
>
> When shared_ptr is created by calling std::make_shared or
>   std::allocate_shared, the memory for both the control block and the
>   managed object is created with a single allocation. The managed object
>   is constructed in-place in a data member of the control block. When
>   shared_ptr is created via one of the shared_ptr constructors, the
>   managed object and the control block must be allocated separately. In
>   this case, the control block stores a pointer to the managed object.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a potential subtle bug: in `sp(new int)` you fist allocate an int (whose pointer is given to `sp`), than sp itself has to allocate a control block (will contain the counters and the deleter).

Now, if doing this last allocation `sp` fails (low memory) you are left with a heap allocated int whose pointer is not held by anyone, and thus impossible to delete. (memory leak).