# Why must shared_ptr<> allocate for the control block and managed object separately?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, make-shared

This linked question asked if the `make_shared<>` function and the `shared_ptr<>` constructor differ.

[What happens when using make_shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779929/what-happens-when-using-make-shared)

Part of the answer was that `make_shared<>` will usually allocate memory for both the pointed to object and smart pointer control block in a single allocation. The `shared_ptr<>` constructors use two allocations.

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) states that the constructors "must" do so but no reason is given.

Why is this? Is it for some reason impossible? Or is it forbidden by the standard for some other reason?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Think about how the `std::shared_ptr` constructor works:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo());
```

First the `new Foo()` expression is evaluated; `::operator new` allocates memory for the `Foo` object and then constructs it.  The resulting pointer is passed in as an argument to the `std::shared_ptr` constructor.

See the problem?  The `Foo` allocation has already been performed!  The smart pointer constructor has *no option* to allocate room for both the control block and the object in the same allocation, since it was not responsible for allocating memory for the object.

`std::make_shared`, on the other hand, is in charge of *both* allocations and so it *is* possible to allocate room for both in one heap allocation, and then placement-new-construct both the object and control block within that one allocation.

Comment: oh my... it was a long day today, and uh, yeah... X-P thanks!