# Why are two raw pointers to the managed object needed in std::shared_ptr implementation?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, shared-ptr

Here's a quote from cppreference's implementation note section of `std::shared_ptr`, which mentions that there are two different pointers(as shown in bold) : the one that can be returned by `get()`, and the one holding the actual data within the control block.

> In a typical implementation, `std::shared_ptr` holds only two pointers:
>
> 1. **the stored pointer (one returned by `get()`)**
> 2. a pointer to control block
>
> The control block is a dynamically-allocated object that holds:
>
> 1. **either a pointer to the managed object or the managed object itself**
> 2. the deleter (type-erased)
> 3. the allocator (type-erased)
> 4. the number of `shared_ptrs` that own the managed object
> 5. the number of `weak_ptrs` that refer to the managed object
>
> The pointer held by the `shared_ptr` directly is the one returned by `get()`, while the pointer or object held by the control block is the one that will be deleted when the number of shared owners reaches zero. These pointers are not necessarily equal.

My question is, why are two different pointer(the two in bold) needed for the managed object (in addition to the pointer to the control block)? Doesn't the one returned by `get()` suffice? And why aren't these pointers necessarily equal?

Comment: IIUC this implies that there are actually, potentially at least, *three* pointers involved: 1. Something returned by get(); 2. Potentially a pointer *within* the control block to the object which will be deleted eventually; 3. A pointer to the control block. Two of them are held by the shared ptr proper; the third one resides inside the control block.

Comment: This is a different question, as I pointed out in my previous comment. It is not concerned with control block vs. object but with the fact that there are *two* pointers to "the object" which may even be different (or there'd be no need to hold two of them). *Plus* the ptr to the control block. (And the answer has apparently to do with the aliasing shared_ptr constructor.)

Comment: From my understanding, the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26351926 is about the  difference between the two construction methods, but still doesn't explain why two possibly different allocation is needed at the first place.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider OK, I found the question confusing and ambiguous. It certainly _could_ be asking something different from what I thought.

Answer (score 55):

The reason for this is that you can have a `shared_ptr` which points to something else than what it owns, and that is by design. This is implemented using the constructor listed as nr. 8 on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr):

```
template< class Y >
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T *ptr );
```

A `shared_ptr` created with this constructor *shares ownership* with `r`, but points to `ptr`. Consider this (contrived, but illustrating) code:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> creator()
{
  using Pair = std::pair<int, double>;

  std::shared_ptr<Pair> p(new Pair(42, 3.14));
  std::shared_ptr<int> q(p, &(p->first));
  return q;
}
```

Once this function exits, only a pointer to the `int` subobject of the pair is available to client code. But because of the shared ownership between `q` and `p`, the pointer `q` keeps the entire `Pair` object alive.

Once dealloacation is supposed to happen, the pointer to the entire `Pair` object must be passed to the deleter. Hence the pointer to the `Pair` object must be stored somewhere alongside the deleter—in other words, in the control block.

For a less contrived example (probably even one closer to the original motivation for the feature), consider the case of pointing to a base class. Something like this:

```
struct Base1
{
  // :::
};

struct Base2
{
  // :::
};

struct Derived : Base1, Base2
{
 // :::
};

std::shared_ptr<Base2> creator()
{
  std::shared_ptr<Derived> p(new Derived());
  std::shared_ptr<Base2> q(p, static_cast<Base2*>(p.get()));
  return q;
}
```

Of course, the real implementation of `std::shared_ptr` has all the implicit conversions in place so that the `p`-and-`q` dance in `creator` is not necessary, but I've kept it there to resemble the first example.

Comment: Conversion from derived classes to base classes is less contrived of an example.

Comment: I think the example is nice enough as it stands. The point is that we point to a part of something which is managed as an atomic entity, and a pair is probably the most trivial and unambiguous example. Inheritance here is just a special form of "being a part of something".

Comment: @Angew: Not ew at you. Ew at C++. The fact that this is pretty much the cleanest example possible to form just goes to support my point!

Comment: I agree with @LightnessRacesinOrbit, if you created a pair, you should handle this ownership as a pair, not trying to split the object between owners. seems like a bad design to begin with. but yet again, the comitee sometimes fails to deliver

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree with the "ew" part. the rest is my additions :)

Comment: Very interesting.  I always thought the pointer in the shared_ptr was an optimization to avoid double indirection of going through the control block.

Answer (score 2):

Additional link to @Angew 's answer:

> Peter Dimov, Beman Dawes and Greg Colvin proposed shared_ptr and weak_ptr for inclusion in the Standard Library via the first Library Technical Report (known as TR1). The proposal was accepted and eventually went on to become a part of the C++ standard in its 2011 iteration.
>
> [boost smart pointer history](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#history)

In this [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2351.htm), the authors pointed out that the usage of "Shared Pointer Aliasing":

> Advanced users often require the ability to create a shared_ptr instance p that shares ownership with another (master) shared_ptr q but points to an object that is not a base of *q. *p may be a member or an element of *q, for example. This section proposes an additional constructor that can be used for this purpose.

So they add an additional pointer into the control block.

Answer (score 0):

One inescapable need for a control block is to support weak pointers.  It is not always feasible to notify all weak pointers on destruction of an object (in fact, it is almost *always* infeasible).  Accordingly, the weak pointers need something to point at until they have all gone away.  Thus, some block of memory has to hang around.  That block of memory is the control block.  Sometimes they may be allocated together, but allocating them separately allows you to reclaim a potentially expensive object while keeping around the cheap control block.

The general rule is that the control block persists as long as there exists a single shared pointer or weak pointer referring to it, while the object is allowed to be reclaimed the instant there are no shared pointers pointing at it.

This also allows for cases where the object is brought into shared ownership after its allocation.  `make_shared` may be able to bundle these two concepts into one block of memory, but `shared_ptr<T>(new T)` must first allocate T, and then figure out how to share it after the fact.  When this is undesirable, boost has a related concept of `intrusive_ptr` which does its reference counting directly inside the object rather than with a control block (you have to write increment and decrement operators yourself to make this work).

I have seen shared pointer implementations which do not have a control block.  Instead, the shared pointers develop a linked-list between themselves.  As long as the linked-list contains 1 or more shared_ptrs, the object is still alive.  However, this approach is more complicated in a multithreading scenario because you have to maintain the linked list rather than just a simple ref count.  Its runtime is also likely to be worse in many scenarios where you are assigning and re-assigning shared_ptrs repeatedly, because the linked-list is more heavy-weight.

It is also possible for a high-performance implementation to pool allocate the control blocks, driving the cost of using them to nearly zero.

Comment: The question is "Why does the control block contain a copy of the stored pointer",  not "Why is there a control block?"

Answer (score -1):

Let look at a `std::shared_ptr<int>` 
This is a reference counted smart pointer to an `int*`. Now the `int*` holds no reference counting information and the `shared_ptr` object itself cannot hold the reference counting information since it may well be destructed well before the reference count drops down to zero.

This means that we must have an intermediate object to hold the control information that is guaranteed to remain persistent until the reference count drops to zero.

Having said that,if you create `shared_ptr` with `make_shared` both the `int` and the control block will be created in contiguous memory making dereferencing much more efficient.

Comment: You did not answer the question as from your explanation only pointer to control block is sufficient, and `get()` could just return pointer to actual object inside control block.

Comment: As I understand the question (and tried to clarify it), the question is not why there's "a pointer to the control block" and "a pointer to the object." The question is why there's "a pointer to the control block", then "a pointer to the object, stored inside the `shared_ptr`", and then "a pointer to the object, stored inside the control block."

Comment: @Angew question is `why there are TWO raw pointers` when one is sufficient

Comment: @Slava Yes; I was addressing doron with my comment.

Comment: @Slava I think the original question is ambiguous. Yes, it asks why there are two pointers, but it asks why we can't just store the pointer to be returned by `get()`. That is, OP seems to think the control block either is unncessary or could be referenced by the `get()` pointer. Neither of those is an option in the case described by this answer.

Comment: @DavidK first question "(in addition to the pointer to the control block" removes that ambiquity. Looks like OP mistakenly thinks that `get()` returns pointer to the control block.

Comment: @Slava I think the point of the original question was that OP probably _does_ think that `get()` returns a pointer to the control block (or else doesn't understand why the control block is needed). But the question has been changed (not by OP!) so that this interpretation is no longer possible. I find this more confusing, not less, but I guess I'll just move on to something else.

Comment: @DavidK Sorry for the confusion. Angew got my points right. I think it's clearer now with the latest revision

Comment: @btshengsheng I'm sorry that I misunderstood the original question. I'm glad the question you meant to ask has been clarified. I hope you find Angew's response answers your question--it looks good to me.