# Shared Pointer query in an interview

Tags: c++, c++14, smart-pointers

which is better among the following codes

```
int  *a=new int();
shared_ptr<int> sh(a);
```

or this

```
shared_ptr<int> sh(new int());
```

The interviewer was hinting that the first case has a problem and make_shared eliminates that problem.
Can anybody point me to the right answer?

Comment: Both cases have the same exact problem.

Comment: in both cases `new` is used. which is not really a problem per se, but in modern c++, you are advised to avoid manual dynamic allocation. `make_shared` hides the allocation behind a library function.

Comment: When speaking about "better" or "worse", there always needs to be some context. Those two snippets on their own doesn't really mean anything on their own, without context. Such interview questions should always be met with a request for more details. And if none are given, then it's a bad sign that you need to keep in mind when considering the possibility of employment there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens when using make\_shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779929/what-happens-when-using-make-shared)

Comment: The only problem with the first variant, is that you still have `a` variable around. If the shared pointer happens to be destroyed, `a` would become a dangling pointer to deleted data. It would be invalid to use value pointed by `a`

Comment: Does not apply here, but `shared_ptr<foo> sh(new int(),g());` can cause a leak when `g` throws an exception. Thats one issue `std::make_shared` solves. That is solves the issue sometimes is reason enough to prefer it always.

Comment: The problem with this question is the example does not correlate with `make_shared eliminates that problem`.  Is this a question about using `make_shared` (which I suspect it is) or is it a question about using a temporary (which I suspect it isn't)

Answer (score 3):

> which is better among the following codes

None of the two.

> The interviewer was hinting that the first case has a problem and make_shared eliminates that problem.

One major issue that `make_shared` solves is exception safety. This is explained [here](https://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF478/docs/Cpp/en/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared.html):

> Moreover, code such as `f(std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(42)), g())` can cause a memory leak if g throws an exception because `g()` may be called after `new int(42)` and before the constructor of `shared_ptr<int>`. This doesn't occur in `f(std::make_shared<int>(42), g())`, since two function calls are never interleaved.

In your code example this is not an issue. However, that `make_shared` solves an issue sometimes is reason enough to prefer it always. Otherwise, both examples are equally poor for the use a raw `new` which should be avoided generally (cf eg https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly and other bullets from the c++ code guideline).

> Can anybody point me to the right answer?

What specifically the interviewer wanted to hear as answer only they can know. For a single integer you probably want just

```
int a = 0;
```

Comment: The question is tagged C++14, so this is indeed correct, Only with C++17 is it guaranteed that function argument evaluation is not interleaved.  Therefore, in C++17 `f(std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(42)), g())` is finally safe. `g()` is called first or last, and in neither case does it matetr whether `g()` throws.

Comment: @MSalters afaik there are other examples that `make_shared` already fixed before c++17. The one i included was just the first one I found. I didnt consider it too important for the question at hand, because its only `new int` that can throw in OPs code and it wouldnt cause a leak

Answer (score 3):

The first case will create another instance of pointer, which make let other user to accidentally delete a pointer that has already been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

As @463035818-is-not-an-ai already answered, the intentions of the interviewer are only known to themselves. Also already stated: both alternatives are equivalent. Maybe s/he wanted to evaluate your knowledge about `make_shared`, or modern C++ in general.

The current documentation of `make_shared` you'll find here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared .
Until C++17 exception safety indeed was an issue in certain situations.

An interesting difference is the number of allocations that are done:

- two allocations for `shared_ptr<int> sh(new int());`,
- one allocation for `auto sh = make_shared<int>();`.

See the "notes" for all details.

Answer (score 2):

"make_shared" is a safer and more robust way to allocate memory dynamically and associate it with a "shared_ptr". It is generally recommended to use "make_shared" when working with shared_ptr because it offers better exception safety and improved performance in some cases (as it can reduce memory overhead by combining memory allocation for the control block and the pointed object).